# Upgrading Elastic search from 7.0x to 8.0x

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

const { body } = await this.elasticSearch.search(x);
i get the following error : Property 'body' does not exist on type 'SearchResponse<unknown, Record<string, AggregationsAggregate>>'.

I upgraded from 7.0 to 8.0 and unable to find solution to the error

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/8.0/changelog-client.html#_the_returned_value_of_api_calls_is_the_body_and_not_the_http_related_keys) of the JavaScript client 8.0, we can read the following:

> The returned value of API calls is the body and not the HTTP related keys

So the response your get is the SearchResponse object

```
const response = await this.elasticSearch.search(x);
```

If you want to access the search response as you used to you can specify your call as follows:

```
const {body} = await client.search(x, {
  meta: true              <----- add this
})
console.log(response) // { body: SearchResponse, statusCode: number, headers: object, warnings: array }
```

The SearchResponse object will now be accessible via the `body` property of the call results.

Comment: Property 'statusCode' does not exist on type 'SearchResponse<unknown, Record<string, AggregationsAggregate>>'.ts(2339) when i check for response.statusCode,

Comment: Have you specified `meta: true` as described in my answer? If you want to keep the old behavior in order to access metadata fields you have to add that

Comment: yes it resolved that, now when i code this  if (response.statusCode !== 200) response.statusCode shows error. [const response = await this.elasticSearch.search(x);]

Answer (score 0):

The `search` method directly returns the response data, so there's no need to access a body property in ES v8.

> In version 7.x, the client's methods returned an object with a body
> property that contained the response data. However, in version 8.x,
> the client's methods directly return the response data, so there's no
> need to access a body property. This is likely the cause of the error
> you're seeing.

You should be able to fix the error by simply removing `.body` from your code. So, your code should look like this:

```
const body = await this.elasticSearch.search(x);
```